# Ambiguity in routes matching

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, restify

[`Restify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify) is hitting incorrect routes and creating ambiguity.

I have 2 routes:

```
apiRouter.get({ path: '/goals/:id', version: '1.0.0' }, goals.getGoal);
apiRouter.get({ path: '/goals/mute', version: '1.0.0' }, lists.getGoalMute);
```

When I request on `/goals/mute` it gets on `/goals/:id`.

I switched the routes(*moved the lower one to up*):

```
apiRouter.get({ path: '/goals/mute', version: '1.0.0' }, lists.getGoalMute);
apiRouter.get({ path: '/goals/:id', version: '1.0.0' }, goals.getGoal);
```

now request gets on the correct route `/goals/mute`.

I don't understand this behavior, what is the matching criteria `restify` uses?

Answer (score 3):

Your routes are similar. So now everything depends on the order of routes.

`/goals/:id` is exactly same to `/goals/mute`.

```
/goals/:id      /goals/something    //here "something" will be "id"
/goals/mute     /goals/something    //here "something" will be "mute"
```

You will have to change the order of routes:

```
/goals/mute
/goals/:id
```

Now it will match first with `/goals/mute` and then with `/goals/:id`.

So if you hit `/goals/` it will go for `/goals/:id`.

Answer (score 0):

Routes are matched in order of their creation.

Since `/goals/:id` matches `/goals/mute`, if you define the former before the latter, it will match before the more specific route for `/goals/mute`.

Comment: So what should I do so it gets on the correct route ?

Comment: Put more specific routes (`/goals/mute`) before less specific ones (`/goals/:id`).